# WPF Change button style at runtime

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to turn on or off a style at runtime using a Toggle Switch.
I have added the style to a resource dictionary but im not sure how to make some C# code to load or unload the resource. All of my buttons are using a dynamic resource of "PassiveGlowButton" and when i use a toggle switch i would like it to remove the "PassiveGlowButton" so its using the style of "GlowButton"

The code behind "GlowButton" This is the code i want to apply when the toggle is on. This is in App.Xaml under Application.resources, resourceDictionary:

```
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="GlowButton"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect  ShadowDepth="5" Color="WhiteSmoke" BlurRadius="18"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.ShadowDepth"
                                 From="3.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                 AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <!-- Mouse over glow -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.BlurRadius"
                                 From="45.0" To="17.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                 AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.BlurRadius"
                                 From="15.0" To="15.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                 AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
```

> Update
>   I have been able to set the style using a button but it will only apply to a button called Testbttn. Is there a way to change it to apply to Button.Style? If i use this method it also looses the storyboard of the button for some reason

```
        Style style = this.FindResource("PassiveGlowButton") as Style;
        TestBttn.Style = style;
```

> Update 2: The solution was to create 3 styles, one the button uses from load and then 2 others, one with a blank button and one with the style i wanted.
>   I have attached the code i used to swap between the styles.

```
private void ButtonStyle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources["PassiveGlowButton"] = Application.Current.Resources["PassiveGlowButtonOn"];
    }


    private void ButtonStyle_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources["PassiveGlowButton"] = Application.Current.Resources["PassiveGlowButtonOff"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

What you're asking may be best redesigned to use `VisualStateManager`.

Another option is redesigning the styles into a StyleViewModel.  (I recommend using a enum and typing your styles so that the VM can live / reference separate from the styles themselves)  If you do this properly you can change the style type and the styles binding will update.

Finally you can use `DynamicResource` as the style and make a default style resource that's set else where.  Styles, when used as a resource, can have the same key in separate dictionaries.  The names overlapped so the last one in (or closest to the control requesting it in the hierarchy) will be the one to get used.  You can re-arrange the style order or add / remove them but the controls won't update until the next time they are loaded.

Each is a little tricky to implement and although I like `VisualStateManager` I'm a fan of the binding fix (option 2) myself.  There's a difference between the two; so I don't want this to confuse you or start a debate.  I'm just illustrating options.

Here's a quick example of binding styles if you do prefer to go that route which will fix your problem IMO.

**Example:**

**Styles**

```
<Application x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="StyleA"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="4" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="StyleB"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Enum**

```
namespace Question_Answer_WPF_App.ViewModels
{
    public enum Styles
    {
        StyleA,
        StyleB
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Question_Answer_WPF_App.ViewModels
{
    public class StylesViewModel : NotifyModel
    {
        private Styles selectedStyle;

        public StylesViewModel()
        {
            SelectStyleCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectStyle);
        }

        public Styles SelectedStyle
        {
            get { return selectedStyle; }
            set
            {
                selectedStyle = value;
                Notify();
            }
        }

        public ICommand SelectStyleCommand { get; }

        private void SelectStyle(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Styles style) SelectedStyle = style;
        }
    }
}
```

**Converter**

```
using Question_Answer_WPF_App.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Question_Answer_WPF_App.Views
{
    public class StyleTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var result = Application.Current.Resources["StyleA"];
            if (value is Styles style)
            {
                switch (style)
                {
                    case Styles.StyleB:
                        result = Application.Current.Resources["StyleB"];
                        break;
                    case Styles.StyleA:
                    default:
                        result = Application.Current.Resources["StyleA"];
                        break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            => DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.Views.StylesTestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App.Views">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ViewModels:StylesViewModel x:Key="StylesViewModel" />
        <local:StyleTypeConverter x:Key="StyleTypeConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{Binding SelectedStyle, Source={StaticResource StylesViewModel}, Converter={StaticResource StyleTypeConverter}}"
                Command="{Binding SelectStyleCommand, Source={StaticResource StylesViewModel}}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Static ViewModels:Styles.StyleA}"
                Content="Select Style A" />
        <Button Style="{Binding SelectedStyle, Source={StaticResource StylesViewModel}, Converter={StaticResource StyleTypeConverter}}"
                Command="{Binding SelectStyleCommand, Source={StaticResource StylesViewModel}}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Static ViewModels:Styles.StyleB}"
                Content="Select Style B" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Results**

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is what im looking for but i wouldnt know where to start changing it all to a StyleViewModel, i was hoping more allong the lines of using a Dynamic resource as all of my buttons are using 
Style="{DynamicResource PassiveGlowButton}"

Comment: Then you just use the same name for the resources.  Make them all GlowStyle or something.  Then remove the existing and add the one to change when you want it.  Problem is, if it's a problem, the control needs to reload to except this change.  So, the next time that view is produced it will show the new style.  I like having most views (the ones that can be) static so this never works for me.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, i have updated my question with my solution. Thank you for the help :)